# Cake PHP 2.X set Exception Handling at mail sending time

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I have create function mail sending and mail send successfully but error handling how to set i don't know ?

Comment: I have found solutions on my self

 try {
         return $email->send();
         // success`
      }
      catch (SocketException $exception) {
          $name = 'Mark Haddin';
          $etr_mail_error = 'Mail Sending Issues Username:- '.$name; 
          CakeLog::Write('etr_mail_error',$etr_mail_error);
  

    }

Comment: Please add every relevant information to the question, not to the comment section. And what does it mean that you don't know how to set error handling?

Comment: Hello @NicoHaase yes sis i don't know how to set error handling.

Comment: Yes @NicoHaase i don't know.

Comment: Have you tried using Google to find help for error handling? It's a basic concept in PHP....